# Bluemix Apache Spark UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ibm-cloud, user-defined-functions

I am running this code in the Bluemix Apache Spark service, which worked a couple of days ago:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
# define timedelta function (obtain duration in seconds)
from datetime import datetime

#Function for deriving difference between two time points because Spark does not support it natively
def time_delta(y,x): 
    delta = x - y
    return int(delta.total_seconds()/60)

diff = udf(time_delta, IntegerType())

#Register user defined function
sqlContext.registerFunction("udf_diff", time_delta, returnType=IntegerType())


res3 = res2.withColumn("waittime", diff(res2["last_bike_time"], res2["bike_came_time"]))


res3.count()
```

I am doing some Spark computation before this part of the code (maps, joins etc) and that works fine, but when I try to define a udf, I get this error.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-2f188d63cae0> in <module>()
      9     return int(delta.total_seconds()/60)
     10 
---> 11 diff = udf(time_delta, IntegerType())
     12 
     13 #Register user defined function

/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in udf(f, returnType)    1595     [Row(slen=5), Row(slen=3)]    1596     """
-> 1597     return UserDefinedFunction(f, returnType)    1598     1599 blacklist = ['map', 'since', 'ignore_unicode_prefix']

/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in
__init__(self, func, returnType, name)    1556         self.returnType = returnType    1557         self._broadcast = None
-> 1558         self._judf = self._create_judf(name)    1559     1560     def _create_judf(self, name):

/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in
_create_judf(self, name)    1567         pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command, self)    1568         ctx = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
-> 1569         jdt = ctx._ssql_ctx.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())    1570         if name is None:    1571             name = f.__name__ if hasattr(f, '__name__') else f.__class__.__name__

/usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in
_ssql_ctx(self)
    689             raise Exception("You must build Spark with Hive. "
    690                             "Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run "
--> 691                             "build/sbt assembly", e)
    692 
    693     def _get_hive_ctx(self):

Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o208))
```

Could it be that they changed something in the Spark build (IBM)?

Comment: Can you show how you create input columns?

Comment: Did you import `pyspark.sql.functions.udf`?

Comment: @zero323 The input columns are a product of a sql query, but that has nothing to do with the exception because the exception happens in the line when defining the udf

Comment: @WoodChopper I did in an earlier notebook cell